# How long does it take to get an In-App Purchase approved for App Store Promotions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have a few In App Purchases for my app and they are approved and live within my app.

Recently I have uploaded an update to include the protocol method `paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct)` to process App Store Promotions.

I also uploaded the required promotional image for my IAPs.

For some reason, the Promotion seems stuck "In Review". It has been 12 days since I uploaded the promotional images. Can someone share his/her experience with how long it takes for these promotions to be reviewed? Should I contact the review team or just wait it out?
[image: IAP stuck in review]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested, I contacted support via developer.apple.com and the same day the metadata got approved.